# Classpath wildcards in AspectJ

Tags: java, classpath, aspectj

I'm using the AspectJ compiler (AJC) and need to reference several hundred .jars in a very nested directory.

When using AJC, I can configure the classpath by adding the -classpath parameter and specifying all dependencies delimited by a semicolon. If I input every .jar file, this works well. However I am not able to use any wildcards. I've tried * and \ and just plain , but none of that works.

Is there any way to specify a wildcard for the classpath parameter in AJC?

Comment: Are you protecting the `*` character from the shell? What happens when it "doesn't work"?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean by protecting the character from the shell. I specify it this way: "c:\<path>\ *";"c:\<path>\ *"; and so on (there is no space betwen the backslash and the asterisk).When it doesn't work, I get a very long list of "can't determine superclass of type XYZ" errors.